# How to write a method for OrderBy lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the code:

```
        var trips = _db.Trips
                        .OrderBy(u => u.TripStops.Where(p=>p.StopTypeId == destinationTypeId).OrderByDescending(c=>c.StopNo).Select(p=>p.Appt).FirstOrDefault())
```

and this part (sort by appt for the last TripStop with type = destinationTypeId) should be used in many places in code.

I want to write a method like:

```
private xxx LastTripStopAppt(...)
{
}
```

and then use it like:

```
        var trips = _db.Trips
                        .OrderBy(LastTripStopAppt(u))
```

But a little confused how to implement this method correctly.

PS. I have tried to do it as

```
    private DateTime? ReturnLastDeliveryAppointment(Trip u, int destinationTypeId)
    {
        return u.TripStops.Where(p => p.StopTypeId == destinationTypeId).OrderByDescending(c => c.StopNo).Select(p => p.Appt).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

and then

```
.OrderBy(u => ReturnLastDeliveryAppointment(u, destinationTypeId))
```

but I get an error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]
>   ReturnLastDeliveryAppointment(Infrastructure.Asset.Trips.Trip, Int32)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Tomer added my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature is probably something like:

```
private Expression<Func<Trip, apptType>> LastTripStopAppt(...)
```

where `appType` is the type of `p.Appt`

You'll need to pass as a parameter to this method the `destinationTypeId`.

So, if `appType` is a `string`:

```
private static Expression<Func<Trip, string>> LastTripStopAppt(int destinationTypeId)
{
    return u => u.TripStops.Where(p=>p.StopTypeId == destinationTypeId).OrderByDescending(c=>c.StopNo).Select(p=>p.Appt).FirstOrDefault();
}
```